# How to decode multi-layers nested JSON String and display in PHP?

Tags: php, json

I know how to decode a JSON string and get the data from one dimensional array but how to get the data from the nested array?
Below is my code:

```
$data = json_decode($json);
```

and below is the JSON return value:

```
{
      "area_metadata": [
        {
          "name": "A",
          "label_location": {
            "latitude": 1,
            "longitude": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "B",
          "label_location": {
            "latitude": 1,
            "longitude": 1
          }
        }   
      ],
     "items": [
            {
              "update_timestamp": "2017-05-02T09:51:20+08:00",
              "timestamp": "2017-05-02T09:31:00+08:00",
              },
              "locations": [
                {
                  "area": "A",
                  "weather": "Showers"
                },
                {
                  "area": "B",
                  "weather": "Cloudy"
                }
              ]
            }
        ]}
```

I had tested:

```
echo $data->items->locations[0]->area;
```

but I got this error

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

Also,I tried to convert JSON into array instead of object:

```
$data = json_decode($json,true);


if (isset($data)) 
{
    foreach ($data->items->locations as $location) 
    {
            if (empty($location["area"])) { continue; }
            if ($location["area"] == "A") 
            {
                echo $location["weather"];

            }


    }
}
```

but it also not working.

Could anyone can advise which step that I did wrongly?
Thanks!

Edited:
Below is the pastebin link with full JSON content.
https://pastebin.com/cewszSZD

Comment: It appears that your JSON is malformed, are you sure this is the exact JSON string you are trying to decode? The decode might "fail" due to the malformed JSON.

Comment: Not responding to my question does not help solving your problem. I understand it if you cannot be here all the time, but people appreciate it if you respond a little sooner.

Comment: I missed out a "}", just added it back to the JSON Data.Thanks.

Comment: I didn't paste the whole JSON data here,cos it was very long,but the overall structure is similar.

Comment: @TomUdding Thanks for your prompt reply.I live in Asia time zone and it is midnight now,I will try my best to reply asap.

Comment: When you do: `$data = json_decode($json,true);` try to use `var_dump()` to se, how the arrays are formed.

Comment: Ah I see, no need to hurry then. It might be better if you provide the whole JSON string (either via a Gist or Pastebin). The edited JSON is still malformed.

Comment: @uikolas `var_dump` will return `NULL` for the provided JSON since it is malformed.

Comment: Yes, I know that. Maybe the author will post all json content. :)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/cewszSZD

Comment: This is the whole JSON data that I got

Comment: Thanks, that JSON is valid, I'll write a sample code in a second.

Comment: Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Items is an array, not an object, you just need something like `echo $data->items[0]->locations[0]->area;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The JSON you provided (in your question) is malformed and using `json_decode()` on it will result in `NULL`. Thus nothing will happen when you try to access the decoded object because it doesn't exist.*

The full JSON you provided is valid and the reason why your code didn't yield any results is because in `items` there is an "inner"-array:

```
(...) 
["items"] => array(1) {
    [0] => array(4) {
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        ["update_timestamp"] => string(25) "2017-05-02T09:21:18+08:00" 
        ["timestamp"] => string(25) "2017-05-02T09:07:00+08:00" 
        ["valid_period"] => array(2) { 
            ["start"] => string(25) "2017-05-02T09:00:00+08:00" 
            ["end"] => string(25) "2017-05-02T11:00:00+08:00" 
        } 
        ["forecasts"] => array(47) { 
            [0] => array(2) { 
                ["area"] => string(10) "Ang Mo Kio" 
                ["forecast"] => string(19) "Partly Cloudy (Day)" 
            }
            (...)
```

You'll have to access that array through key `0`, for arrays it will look like this:

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
echo $data['items'][0]['forecasts'][0]['area'];
//                 ^^^
```

And for objects like this:

```
$data = json_decode($json);
echo $data->items[0]->forecasts[0]->area;
//               ^^^
```

The second `0` changes the location (the different arrays in the `forecasts` array).

You can check the output [here](https://3v4l.org/uT1Lh) (array approach) and [here](https://3v4l.org/c4VZA) (object approach).

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to help if you post all the JSON data or link to a screenshot of it. Try:

```
$items[0]['locations'][0]['area'];
```

Single quotes on strings, no quotes on numbers.

Comment: You could put all the areas in an array with: 
`$areas = array();
    foreach($data['items'] as $area)
        $areas[] = $area['forecasts'][0]['area'];`