# Printing a nested JSON Array value

Tags: php, arrays, json

I've been trying to find ways to print the individual data but can't seem to figured out where I'm going wrong.

I started with this but I get no results. Before this I tried nesting loops but also got nowhere either.

```
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$d = json_decode($data, true);
foreach($d as $k=>$v){
echo $v['value']['displayName'];
}
```

Then I tried the following with only got me some of the results. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with this.

```
foreach(json_decode($data,true) as $d){
 foreach($d as $k=>$v){
  foreach($v as $kk=>$vv){
   echo $kk.$vv;
   }
  }
}
```

The JSON looks like the following:

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "",
      "name": "",
      "etag": "",
      "type": "Microsoft.SecurityInsights/alertRules",
      "kind": "Scheduled",
      "properties": {
        "incidentConfiguration": {
          "createIncident": true,
          "groupingConfiguration": {
            "enabled": false,
            "reopenClosedIncident": false,
            "lookbackDuration": "PT5M",
            "matchingMethod": "AllEntities",
            "groupByEntities": [],
            "groupByAlertDetails": null,
            "groupByCustomDetails": null
          }
        },
        "entityMappings": [
          {
            "entityType": "Account",
            "fieldMappings": [
              {
                "identifier": "FullName",
                "columnName": "AccountCustomEntity"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "entityType": "IP",
            "fieldMappings": [
              {
                "identifier": "Address",
                "columnName": "IPCustomEntity"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "queryFrequency": "P1D",
        "queryPeriod": "P1D",
        "triggerOperator": "GreaterThan",
        "triggerThreshold": 0,
        "severity": "Medium",
        "query": "",
        "suppressionDuration": "PT1H",
        "suppressionEnabled": false,
        "tactics": [
          "Reconnaissance",
          "Discovery"
        ],
        "displayName": "MFA disabled for a user",
        "enabled": true,
        "description": "Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA) helps prevent credential compromise. This alert identifies when an attempt has been made to diable MFA for a user ",
        "alertRuleTemplateName": null,
        "lastModifiedUtc": "2022-11-14T02:20:28.8027697Z"
      }
    },
...
...
...
```

Comment: I have added an answer below, but I did notice that I got a syntax error from your JSON file, make sure your JSON is valid. In your snippet, it ends a bit unexpectedly.

Comment: Ah, yea, that was a small template of the actual JSON data. It just repeats constantly so I left the rest out since it just repeats :)

Comment: That's what I thought too =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can get the display name without a loop. Notice that the `0` is the key value of the array since it doesn't have a name.

We start from the `value`, and we move one layer deeper by selecting the first array `0`. Now we need to select the `properties` and finally, we can get the `displayName` from there.

```php
$displayName = $d["value"][0]["properties"]["displayName"];
echo($displayName);

/*
Here is a quick demonstration:

value:
{
    0:
    {
        ...
        properties:
        {
            ...
            displayName: [We made it!]
        }
    }

}

*/
```

And here is a very good post that explains this in more detail

[How to decode multi-layers nested JSON String and display in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44313448/how-to-decode-multi-layers-nested-json-string-and-display-in-php)

Comment: This helped. So I didn't realize properties was nested inside, which messed me up. I got it now! :)

Comment: That's good to hear! I have recently been struggling with this too so it's all fresh in my memory.  Finding the correct path to the right value can get tricky in big files. I have noticed that going backward from the goal to the beginning can be helpful, just like reversing a maze. Just remember to mark all the parents on your way up and the job is done.